# How to know which LinkButton in a ListView was clicked

Tags: asp.net, listview, linkbutton

I currently have a LinkButton in the ItemTemplate of a ListView. Each button in the ListView should call the same click event handler. However, in the handler I need to know which button was clicked. Is this possible?

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvKeyGroup">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>[<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="lbRemoveAuthGroup_Click" />]</td>
            <td><%# Eval("AuthorizationGroup") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `CommandName` property to each `LinkButton` and handle ListView's `ItemCommand` event.

Also you need to set ListView's `DataKeys` property to your datasource object unique identifier name. The you can get selected row datakey:

```
void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // in assumption that your data item's unique identifier type is Int32
    var dataKey = (int)ListView1.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex].Value; 

    switch(e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Remove":
            // your code here
            break;
    }
}
```

Follow this link for ListView control overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx

Also, watch this video: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-03&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the right route to go. I'm just having a little trouble referencing the data item in my handler. All I can seem to get is the ListViewDataItem which doesn't give me enough information to query the DB to remove the item. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate all the help.