# Imagebutton in a Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, imagebutton

I've got an Imagebutton in my listview, but then I can't type in my code (aspx.cs) in `Imagebutton1.Click`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFotos" runat="server" 
            GroupItemCount="6" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" align="center">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td align="center" height="150px" 
                    style="background-color: #ffffff;color: #ffffff; border:none;" width="142px">

                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem  %>" runat="server" Width="142" Height="142" />                       

                 </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>

            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327665/how-to-know-which-linkbutton-in-a-listview-was-clicked/8327761#8327761

Answer (score 1):

You shoul use listview ItemCommand event.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem  %>" runat="server" Width="142" Height="142" CommandName="Fire_click_event" />
```

```
public void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName != "Fire_click_event")
        {
             // Do what you want in click event
        }
    }
```